# Automatically add a javascript when a certain form field is added

Tags: sitecore-forms

I understand that in order to add a script in Sitecore Forms, I must add it in the script field of the form. However, this could be cumbersome for the content editors since they would have to add the script every time they make a form. Plus, this new custom javascript does not need to be in all forms but only in select forms where a particular field is added.

Is there a way to automatically add that custom script only when a particular field is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following processor to `forms.renderField` pipeline:

```
public class RenderFieldSpecificJavascript : MvcPipelineProcessor<RenderFieldEventArgs>
{
    public override void Process(RenderFieldEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.RenderingSettings.FieldTypeId == "{4EE89EA7-CEFE-4C8E-8532-467EF64591FC}" // your custom field ID
            && HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("ExperienceFormsScriptsKey"))
        {
            var dict = (Dictionary<string, IHtmlString>) HttpContext.Current.Items["ExperienceFormsScriptsKey"];
            dict["MyCustomField"] = new HtmlString("<script src=\"/my-custom-script.js\"></script>");
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <forms.renderField>

                <processor 
                    type="My.Assembly.Namespace.RenderFieldSpecificJavascript, My.Assembly" 
                    patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderField.IncludeConditions, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc']"/>

            </forms.renderField>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

It will render your script at the end of the `<body>`:

[image]

Comment: Would it be cleaner if I did this inside a pipeline?

Comment: @Lala code updated